# awk script adjusting format

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, scripting, awk

I'm trying to use the following awk script to count ***every 1000*** records from file named file.txt and enclose those records between brackets

content of file.txt

12345

23456

43567

```
awk '{ printf $0 " " } NR%1000 == 0 { print "" }' file.txt | sed 's/.*/(&)/'
```

output

```
(12345 23456 43567)
```

I need to assotciate this output with ***mysql bulk delete statement*** such as the following

```
Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (12345,23456,43567);
```

1. I'm unable to add "Delete from ReportingDetail where
   ReportingDetailID IN" to the birnining of every line.
2. I'm unable to add "," between records.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: +1 for good problem statement, sample input, expected output AND some code! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this only with sed:

```
sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/^/Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (/' -e 's/$/)/' file.txt
```

E.g.:

```
$ echo "1 2 3"|sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/^/Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (/' -e 's/$/)/'
Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (1,2,3)
```

Edit - for your update (i.e. when you have numbers on different lines), just prepend what you already had:

```
awk '{ printf $0 " " } NR%1000 == 0 { print "" }' file.txt | sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/^/Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (/' -e 's/,$/)/'
```

E.g.:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3"|awk '{ printf $0 " " } NR%1000 == 0 { print "" }'|sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/^/Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (/' -e 's/,$/)/'
Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (1,2,3)
```

You can also do that without awk like this:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4"|tr "\n" " "|sed -e 's/ /,/g' -e 's/^/Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (/' -e 's/,$/)/'
Delete from ReportingDetail where ReportingDetailID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Note the echo I used is just for testing, i.e. this is what it produces:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4"
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I guess it will take me 100 years to get to were you are today! thanks for your help! you rock!!

Comment: Heh, now I feel like some kind of alien :) (I'm not, scout's honor!) http://xkcd.com/718/ Anyway, glad it worked for you!